# Django Serializer to group fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to build a simple endpoint `/users/` that returns output like the following:

```
{ 
  ids: [
    "e3fa5cbe-e89e-4017-bbd3-546019247932",
    "94c1f979-f122-471b-a694-e748f5d95c25",
    "30f20792-18d9-4db0-8dde-9ad62d239928",
    "2ee0399d-881a-43b5-ad53-a741507e12c1",
    "359b6550-bcfd-4c41-99be-3422cbba3da5"
  ]
}
```

The id's belong to the user objects themselves. I have a model viewset defined as such:

```py
class UserIdViewSet(
    viewsets.ModelViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    serializer_class = IdListSerializer
    filterset_class = UserFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(
            company=self.request.user.get_company()
        )
```

But I am having difficulty writing IdListSerializer. ChatGPT and Copilot suggest variations of the following:

```py
class IdListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.UUIDField())

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {"ids": [str(user.id) for user in self.objects.all()]}
```

But instance is not itterable. We really want the collection not the instance.

Is this possible using DRF without resorting to an APIView?